# How is this Typescript class compatible with this interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript(and OOP). I found the following example in their official documentation:

```
class Student {
    fullName: string;
    constructor(public firstName: string, public middleInitial: string, public lastName: string) {
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
    }
}

interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

function greeter(person : Person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}

let user = new Student("Jane", "M.", "User");

document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

The way I see it, `class Student` doesn't have the property `lastname` and thus shouldn't be compatible with the `interface Person` when the `function greeter` is being called.

What am I missing here?

Comment: But it does have a field lastName. `public lastName: string` this is a shorthand fiedl declaration. This is both a public field and a parameter declaration. That is the meaning of the modifier in the ctor params.

Comment: Ahh..got it. Thanks.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: should have been posted as answer

Comment: @H.B. I'll post it, it did however help me get my  pundit badge so it's no all lost :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class does have a field `lastName`. `public lastName: string` is a shorthand field declaration. This is both a `public` field and a parameter declaration. That is the meaning of the modifier in the constructor parameter. See the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties) for more information